# VSCode API: An inline inputs on specific lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a Gerrit plugin for VSCode to enable users to answer code reviews directly from VSCode.

I got inspired by the Webstorm's inline inputs when dealing with Github pull requests.

As a newbie when it comes to VSCode API, I wonder if you guys can save some time for me.

What I essentially want to do is fetch gerrit comments for a specific commit and somehow, show them inline with those lines of code where the comments were left.

Luckily, Gerrit API is accommodating this and I have the data and now I need some part of the API that would allow me to somehow create some sort of views that would be below or above those lines of code where comments are left.

Aside that, I'd also need an input field below those to be able to answer those reviews directly.

If some of you aren't familiar with Gerrit and code reviews, this is an example:

[image]

In Gerrit, you highlight a specific line of Code and add a review for it. That's essentially what I want to do but inside of VSCode.

Thanks in advance :0)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this at the time of writing is (currently [proposed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Extension-API-process#about-proposed-api)) [comments API](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/edd216eb0cdbe2509d1c035fa12342ebb60399fb/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts#L672-L871). You can read more about this on the [Github Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65076) I've created.